# requestImageForAsset resultHandler block never gets called

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimage, uikit, phasset

I'm trying to load a UIImage from a PHAsset for a collection view cell like so,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    myCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL_ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PHAsset *asset = _assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];
    NSLog(@"asset = %@", asset);

    PHImageRequestOptions *myOpts = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
    myOpts.synchronous = YES;

    [_imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                             targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                            contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                                options:myOpts
                          resultHandler:^(UIImage *myResult, NSDictionary *myInfo) {
                                  NSLog(@"***---info = %@", myInfo);
                                  cell.myImageView.image = myResult;
                              }];


    return cell;
}
```

This runs without error, but no image is sent to the cell and the result handler block never gets called.  The PHAsset is not nil.  TIA

Comment: Are you sure _imageManager is not nil?

Comment: What is _imageManager and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh! I knew I must be doing something stupid!  8-)

Adding this to viewDidLoad solved it.

```
_imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
[self resetCachedAssets];
```

Thanks to trungduc and El Tomato for pointing me in the right direction.